# Enterprise LIbrary and MS Azure Articles?

Tags: azure, enterprise-library

Just wondering if anyone has had any experience using MS Azure and the Enterprise Library? I can't seem to find any articles on this and hoping (really hoping) someone has some?

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Library is big... which part were you particularly interested in?

In general, you won't have any problems, since Azure now supports full trust.  However, some parts won't really make sense... for example, you can't use Enterprise Logging to log to a "C:\MyLog.txt", since you won't be able to log anything to a "local drive" in the cloud.  Perhaps you could write a logging provider to Azure table storage however, for example.

Answer (score 0):

See this whitepaper "[Using classic Enterprise Library 5.0 in Windows Azure](http://entlib.codeplex.com/downloads/get/336804)".

Also, check out the specially designed [Enterprise Library Integration Pack for Windows Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680918%28PandP.50%29.aspx) which introduced 2 new application blocks - the Autoscaling Application Block ("Wasabi") and the Transient Fault Handling Application Block ("Topaz".